# could scrarctl be causing the error message ! LaTeX Error: File `ucs.sty' not found.

Tags: errors

I am working in Ubuntu 10.10 using Gnome.  I wrote this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}



\title{Papa Johns Cheese}
\date{Saturday 25 December 2010}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
---message---

\end{document}
```

I get the above error message in the log file

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ucs.sty' not found
```

Now I have not used LaTeX since 1993, so I went to a beginners tutorial and wrote the hello script and it worked fine when I gave the command
latex hello.  No error.  this started with `\documentclass{article}` So I wondered.

Comment: The document class should not change this. Did you change nothing else at all?

Comment: I did not change anything else.

Comment: There is no reason for loading `ucs` with the `utf8` option passed to `inputenc`. Moreover, with a current (2022) version of LaTeX, loading `ucs` is not recommended and `inputenc` with the `utf8` is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Does `locate ucs.sty` (on a command line) find anything? If not, you need to install the `texlive-latex-extra` package (eg. via Synaptic) or simply install `texlive-full`.

Comment: I installed texlive-latex-extra and then tried Locate ucs.sty and find -name ucs.sty. Still did not find any file.  When I tried latex PapasCheese, it gave me the "File 'ucs.sty' not found" again

Comment: It works now.  I tried Ubuntu Software Center and searched for latex-ucs.  The file given did not have ucs in it but I installed it and then I was able to compile the PapasCheese.tex file.  It only gave a warning message about using something older than 2004. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have the package ucs installed, run

```
                texhash
```

Shoud be enough